# CSS selector - select an item based on what it contains

Tags: css

Is there a way to select with CSS only an item based on what it contains? For example, I am looking for something like this:

```
div:contains(#childDivId) {
    // some code
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Cheers

Comment: You mean select (and style) a parent `div` when one of its children has the required `id`? I don't think that is currently possible with just CSS.

Comment: yes, I know it is easily feasible with jQuery but I am not sure it can be done with css only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly called a "parent selector", and it doesn't exist in CSS. Even the future plans for a [`:has()` selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) indicate that [it will only work as a selector from inside JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), evidenced by the fact that [it's not included in the "fast profile"](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles). So you need JS for this, plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such thing in css3 yet. But CSS4 got :has() selector.
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/

Answer (score 0):

## Unfortunately there are no parent selectors in CSS/CSS3.

- The **css3** selector "General sibling combinator" could maybe used for what you want:
- This matches any F element that is preceded by an E element.

  E ~ F {
      property: value;
  }

---

**Using Javascript**

```
    // JavaScript code:
    document.getElementsByClassName("childDiv")[0].parentNode;

    // jQuery code:
    $('.childDiv').parent().get(0); // This would be the childDiv's parent <div>.
```